# Javascript: conditional increment or decrement inside for loop properties

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I know I can do an IF ELSE, but I need to know if it is possible to set conditional loop, like so:

```
for ( i=0; i<la; dr?(i++):(i--) ) {}
```

or

```
for ( if (dr) { i=0; i<length; i++ } else { i=length-1; i--} ) {}
```

Comment: No. Just split them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another, still compact (moreso, even) but more readable and efficient way to do it would be:

```
var str = 'hello';
for(var i=(dr?0:str.length-1), d=(dr?1:-1); str[i]; i+=d) do_something();
```

And if you put 1 or -1 in `dr`, which makes sense I think:

```
for(var i=+(dr===-1&&str.length-1); str[i]; i+=dr) do_something();
```

Comment: dr is boolean and mostly true. SO I guess your first solution would do.

Comment: I tested your second solution and is great, thank you, you scored.

Answer (score 0):

First is ok. (but you probably have to use `a?b:c` on your end_condition too)
Second is: syntax error ^^

Crazy way:

```
var str = 'hello';
for(i=(dr?0:str.length-1);(dr?i<str.length:i>=0);(dr?i++:i--)) do_something();
```

Right way:

```
   var str = 'hello';
   if(dr)
      for(i=0;i<str.length;i++) do_something();
   else
      for(i=str.length-1;i>=0;i--) do_something();
```

(code not tested)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with the best possible fix for it? Thanks

Comment: I can't since i dont know what you *exactly* try to achieve. (what is `la`? etc...). However if it's for another goal as educative, the other users are right... You might better split it in a condition + 2 different loops...

Comment: la = abbrev, stands for length of active items

Comment: then you want to scan a string from beginning to end, or from end to beginning dependings on dr = true or false ?

Comment: ok i edited, and did it with a string, but it would work the same way for an array...

Comment: Thanks, will check and let you know, I believe the i>=0 instead of i>0 should fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is fine to use a conditional loop but it is not recommended as it becomes really hard for someone new who tries to understand your code. The code is not readable if you use the first syntax. The second syntax is much readable so I think you should prefer to use it.

But if you are are fine to use the first version of the syntax then go with it. You should always use the code which is easiest to read and maintain.

Comment: I ask this question because I don't want same huge code inside for to be written twice, perhaps going with this idea would not produce any performance issue. I don't mind user readability, if it works with IE8+, here we go.

Comment: @thednp:- Thats why I added in my answer, if you dont mind readabiliyt then you can go with any of the option. It will have very minimal or rather no impact as far as the performance is concerned.

Comment: can you please correct my code, the first option, I don't know why I can't eliminate the error in my code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. The first is good and working. 
   for this:

   `for ( i=0; i<4; dr?(i++):(i--) )`

   Check jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r7g5jjph/)
2. **The Second one is NOT ok as for loop  expects an identifier and instead got 'if'**.

Comment: if !dr it will loop indefinitely but the syntax is ok ^^

Comment: Yes, I happen to have experienced that as well, I think my Chrome tab is dead now :)