# Condition loop can change depending other value

Tags: javascript

Maybe it's not possible but I want to be sure.

I have for example this loop very simple (pseudo-code)

```
for( start ; start < end ; start ++) { [...] }
```

But if (start > end) i want something like that :

```
for( start ; start > end ; start --) { [...] }
```

How it's possible (if it is) to make something like that, without duplicate all my loop, or without create a function

Thanks a lot, I hope my question is not stupid.......

Edit : Thanks to yours answers !

```js
var start = 10
var end = 0

for (var cpt = start; start < end ? cpt < end : cpt > end; start < end ? cpt++ : cpt--){
console.log(cpt)
}
```

Comment: This is actually a challenging question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: conditional increment or decrement inside for loop properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29506603/javascript-conditional-increment-or-decrement-inside-for-loop-properties)

Comment: Switch the value of `start` and `end` if `start > end` and use `for( start ; start < end ; start ++)`?

Comment: Why can't you use two loop?

Comment: Thum : it's impossible to switch values of start and end, because in the loop condition, start need to be inferior than end
brk : Because my loop is a bit difficult and I want to be sure that it's impossible toi make what I want before use two loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
for (start; start < end ? start < end : start > end; start < end ? start++ : start--) {[...]};
```

Comment: This will lead to infinite loop. What do you think?

Comment: I think too, but i will try

Comment: It won't, because once the numbers are equal, the middle condition will terminate

Comment: Yes, but if my incrementation is not +1 but +2 ? It can be possible that start never equals to end. No ?

Comment: @Mathieud.o In that case you're right. In that case the conditions can be defined before the for loop and then it will refer to the original values.

Answer (score 2):

use `while`

```js
let start = 3;
let end = 16;

let inc = 5;

while (true) {
  console.log(start);
  if (Math.abs(start - end) < inc) { break; }
  start += start < end ? inc : inc * -1; 
}
```

Comment: It works, only if we increment by +1, but if we increment by +2 ? Maybe it doesn't work.In my example incrementation was simple, but it's a bit more complex in my code

Comment: Thanks to you, it works fine ! But i have choisen an other solution that seems to be more simple to understand ! I have edit my first post !

Comment: @Mathieud.o i've simplified it a bit ;)